# Forcing HTML Escaping in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, html-safe

I'm running into an issue with the rails auto-escaping.  It currently thinks a string is html_safe (which it is), but for display purposes I need it to still escape the html.  Here's the steps the string is taking.

```
my_string = render(:partial => "set_string", :locals => {:item => @item})
<%= my_string %>
```

and the partial is basically

```
<h2>Page Header</h2>
<strong><%= item.name %></strong>
<%= item.body %>
etc
```

My understanding is that because I'm displaying text in a view directly (the h2, etc) it assumes it is safe, and it also properly escapes the item outputs, which makes the whole my_string safe.  So, when I try to display it with the

```
<%= my_string %>
```

It doesn't escape the remaining html.  I tried adding h to force the escaping but that didn't work.

So my question is, is there anyway to force html escaping of a safe string other than calling something on the string that will make it unsafe?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to Sebastien for the suggestion, I wanted to get the real answer here and not buried in the comments:

I looks like this works:

```
<%= raw CGI::escapeHTML(my_string) %>
```

You need the "raw" call otherwise the escapeHTML makes the string unsafe in addition to escaping it so the auto escape double escapes it.

Comment: note, `CGI::escapeHTML` does not escape all entities, e.g. `&acute;` and `&aacute;`

Answer (score 23):

### Escape from ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer in Rails 3+

In this instance `<%= my_string.to_str %>` will double-escape as required.

#### SafeBuffer workings

When a string is escaped by Rails you get an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`. From that point, extra escaping is skipped because the `SafeBuffer` is `html_safe?`. It's a clever solution! There are times though, that we wish to escape such cleverness.

#### Why double-escape?

I needed to *re-escape content generated by tag helpers* to pass generated markup to `data-` attributes. This has also come in handy for displaying template-generated code.

#### Force-escape for a `String` that's `html_safe?`

Call `to_str` on the `SafeBuffer`, which returns a `String`.

```
# Example html safe content
content = content_tag :code, 'codez<>'
content.html_safe? # true

# call .to_str
escaped = content.to_str
escaped.html_safe? # false

# The escaped String will now be re-escaped when used in a template
```

#### The `to_s` gotcha

The `to_s` method looks very much like the `to_str` method.
Don't use `to_s` here, `ActionView::SafeBuffer#to_s` just returns `self`, where `to_str` is called above the `SafeBuffer` context, returning a naturally unsafe `String`.

Comment: The solution is then to use `content.to_str` to re-escape the content

Comment: Thanks @SébastienGrosjean-ZenCocoon I've updated the answer to be more specific to this question :)

Comment: great way to mark it as `unsafe` again, I used it to `render` a partial inside an html attribute: `<div data-content="<%= render(partial: 'my_partial').to_str %>"></div>`

Comment: This doesn't work if the string is an ActionView::OutputBuffer -- to_s keeps it as an OutputBuffer.  @Jason-Logsdon's answer works in this case though.

Comment: I totally agree `to_s` does not work :D however `to_str` still works as intended. I had to squint before I realised this. Updated the code comments to help prevent the gotcha occurring for others.

Answer (score 5):

To interpret the html (it's what i understood you need), you have to use :

```
<%= raw my_string %>
```

Comment: I'm looking to have the HTML to be escaped, not interpreted. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried this : CGI::escapeHTML('Usage: foo "bar" <baz>')

Comment: Looks like this works: <%= raw CGI::escapeHTML(my_string) %>, otherwise the escapeHTML makes it unsafe in addition to escaping it so the auto escape double escapes it.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I was just doing my_string.gsub("","") to make it unsafe but I figured there had to be a better way.  Just update your answer and I'll accept it.