# CKEditor: I want to disallow <ul> tag in WYSWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have used the `allowedContent=true` that stops the HTML cleanup. But now I got stuck with other issue.

Issue is, when I enter the some text like `<li> test text </li>` in source and after I click source and again click source now the text changing to  `<ul><li> test text <\li><\ul>`. It's adding `ul` tag. So I will want to disallow this. Can you advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this can help you [Forcing HTML Escaping in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902255/forcing-html-escaping-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

There's no configuration option which would allow such thing because CKEditor **must** produce valid HTML and the `<ul>` tag is requires in this case.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually in page already <ul> tags embedded. So li tag data keeping in ckeditor after push the data there are 2 ul tags appearing in page. That is the issue

Comment: What if a user creates a list followed by few paragraphs? Will you try to load it inside `<ul>` element? You should not expect that CKEditor will produce only `<li>` elements as such features is not supported.